# Weird behavior when using small caps and slanted fonts with fontspec in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, fontspec, small-caps, libertine, slanted

I use XeLaTeX and the `fontspec` package.

Now, I like to use Linux Libertine as standard font. The slanted (not italics) characters are stored in a different font. Now, to use them with `\slshape`, I have to select them explicitly:

```
\setmainfont[
    SlantedFont={Linux Libertine Slanted O},
    SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
    Mapping=tex-text, Numbers=OldStyle, Variant=01, Ligatures={TeX, Common}, Contextuals=WordFinal,
    % Style=Alternate, Ligatures={Rare, TeX, Common}
            ]{Linux Libertine O}
```

As you can see, the slanted font is selected in the `SlantedFont={Linux Libertine Slanted O}` argument.

When I use `\slshape` in my document now:

```
{\slshape \lipsum[1-2]}
```

It creates the correct slanted text.

*(`\usepackage{lipsum}` is further up in the file.)*

Now, when I want to use small caps I use `\scshape`:

```
{\scshape \lipsum[3-4]}
```

The text is slanted small caps! To circumvent this, I have to comment out the `SlantedFont` argument in `\setmainfont`, this makes the small caps upright, but I lose slanted text capabilities.

How do I make both behave corectly?

Comment: Declare also `SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine O}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding ItalicFeatures gets you part of the way there...my eyes aren't good enough to tell the difference....

```
\setmainfont[
    ItalicFont={Linux Libertine O}, ItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine O Italic}},
    SlantedFont={Linux Libertine Slanted O},
    SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine O},
    SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
    Mapping=tex-text, Numbers=OldStyle, Ligatures={TeX, Common}, Contextuals=WordFinal,
            ]{Linux Libertine O}

 {\slshape Abc}

{\scshape Def}

 {\scshape\itshape Ghi}

{\scshape\slshape Lmn}%
```

an image similar to above....GHI and Lmn are the same...but slanted or italic[image: img]

Comment: It's kinda what I came across.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case it's sufficient to omit the `SmallCapsFeatures` key:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[
    SlantedFont={Linux Libertine Slanted O},
    SmallCapsFont={Linux Libertine O},
    SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
    Mapping=tex-text, Numbers=OldStyle, Ligatures={TeX, Common}, Contextuals=WordFinal,
            ]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
{\slshape Abc}

{\scshape Def}

{\scshape\itshape Ghi}

{\scshape\slshape Lmn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Erm, that's not what I wanted. I want upright small caps. Small caps should only be slanted if used with `\slshape`. You have `{\scshape Def}` and the result is slanted as well, which in my case is incorrect.

Comment: @polemon This is something Will should look into.

Comment: While this solution works partially, I lose the option to make slanted small caps: `{\scshape \slshape blah}` or `{\scshape \itshape blah}` or variants with `\scshape` as second argument don't work anymore.

Comment: That's why I said that Will should have to look into this issue.